# Is there any regex to find package name

Tags: android, package, adb, monkey

I want to run monkey on game 2048 using adb

So, i need package name of 2048, i used

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

to list packages.

I could not find 2048 in it, but the application is installed on my device.
Is there any regex by which i can look for package name using keyword 2048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same command just look for /data/app/ in the list. And if you are using and Linux destro or MAC then you can use ***grep/egrep*** command on output to find it easily

Comment: I am using windows, i checked in data/app and there is nothing matching 2048

Comment: is there any method to display only data/app packages and not system

Answer (score 1):

Just because the app name is "2048" does not mean it is used in the package name. However, I looked up the most popular Google Play game and it does have 2048 in the package name.

You could use `grep` to get the package. The following example will get the path to the APK file:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f | grep 2048 | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d= -f1
...
/data/app/com.estoty.game2048-1.apk
```

An easy way to find out the package name of an app on Google Play is to just search on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps) and look at the last part of the URL:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**com.presselite.the2048game**

Comment: it says 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Are you running this command from windows command prompt or linux terminal? I should have noted that I ran the above line on a rooted device with busybox installed using cygwin.

Comment: Which of the many 2048 games do you have installed? https://play.google.com/store/search?q=2048&c=apps